# Calculate input impedance of Common-gate circuit with feedback

Tags: feedback

The following is from the book [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), Page 278.

The following is used for calculation of input resistance.

[image]

The book said

$$V_{out} = (g_{m1} + g_{mb1}) V_x R_D$$

However, according to KCL.

$$- \frac{V_{out}} {R_D} = -V_x (g_{m1} + g_{mb1}) + \frac{V_{out}} {\frac{1} {s C_1} + \frac{1} {s C_2}}$$

Where am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @G36 Could you take a look if you have time?

Comment: @internet Could you take a look if you have time?

Comment: Afraid you can only *at* people who have commented -- FYI

Comment: What is g_mb1 from? I don't see it explained within the section.

Comment: @TimWilliams I guess \$ g_{mb1}\$ is body effect

Answer (score 1):

A mid-frequency approximation is stated in the above text.  So, the loading effect of C1+C2 and junction capacitances can be ignored (R<sub>D</sub> dominates), and the capacitor divider is assumed a voltage divider of same ratio.